# MKMapItem Center for creating annotations

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mklocalsearch, mkmapitem

I am trying to perform an `MKLocalSearch.Request()` and display the result on my mapView similar to [this tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/) however when I do the search the coordinates returned are off center from where they should be. Where the map displays Brooklyn as an overlay in the center of the borough correctly the annotation is far off center to the left. I've noticed that there are two sets of coordinates contained in `MKMapItem` one the location and the other shown as center when printed to the console. I am not sure how to access the center coordinate but the center coordinate is the correct one in the middle of the screen. How can I access the center coordinate to use as the `MKAnnotation`'s coordinate? Thank you

**Search Code**

```
let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "brooklyn"
searchRequest.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.758896, -73.985130), latitudinalMeters: 2000, longitudinalMeters: 2000)
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

search.start { (response, error) in
    if let error = error{
        print("Error performing search for location")
    }

    if let response = response{
        for item in response.mapItems{
            print("map item returned: \(item)")

            print("latitude: \(item.placemark.coordinate.latitude) longitude: \(item.placemark.coordinate.longitude)")
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            annotation.title = item.name
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> map item returned: Optional(CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+40.64529796,-73.94483550> radius 14090.15', center:<+40.64529796,-73.94483550>, radius:14090.15m))
>   latitude: 40.6924599 longitude: -73.9903805

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the center by casting the `region` property of `MKMapItem`'s `placemark` property from `CLRegion` to `CLCircularRegion`.

```
            if let response = response{
                for item in response.mapItems{
                    print("map item returned: \(item.placemark)")
                    if let region = item.placemark.region as? CLCircularRegion{
                        print("region.center: \(region.center)")
                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.coordinate = region.center
                        annotation.title = item.name
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score -1):

The response has a property called boundingRegion which is an MKCoordinateRegion, so for example you can access it with

```
  response.boundingRegion
```